# Reliable Topic Stats

Tags: hazelcast

We have a Hazelcast cluster (v 3.10.1) running on two windows servers, with multiple java clients connected.
We are using Maps, Queues, Topics and Reliable Topics all of which are working. However in Management Center we are not getting any stats for the reliable topic.

Initially we did not explicitly declare the reliable topic in the hazelcast xml, allowing it to be dynamically created, however the default has 
`<statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>`.
Since we were not getting any stats, we explicitly declared the topic however we are still not receiving any stats.

All other structures (maps, queues, topics) are showing stats correctly.

***EDIT***
Running the following through the man center scripting shows an increment in the cluster publish stats when explictly called through the scripting directly

```
function viewStats(topicName) {
var topic = hazelcast.getReliableTopic(topicName);
topic.publish("foo");
var topicStats = topic.getLocalTopicStats()
return 'Stats => ' + topicStats;
}
viewStats(["YOUR_TOPIC_NAME"]);
```

However publish actions made by remote java clients are not reflected. We have already proved via debugging on the clients that the topic is working and data is being published, but it is not reflected in the man center stats

Comment: Do you see the name of the reliable topic in the Reliable Topics list in Management Center? Or you see and you have zeros as stats?

Comment: Yes the reliable topic is displayed, with both cluster members listed. However publishes and receives is 0 for both members.

Comment: Can you please share the result of the following script after running on Management Center's Scripting tab? https://gist.github.com/alparslanavci/d864c9df50ff4e2fb0922d979485b7b0

Comment: Response from [xxxxxxx]:5701:
Stats => LocalTopicStatsImpl{creationTime=1542989061370, totalPublishes=0, totalReceivedMessages=0}

Response from [yyyyyyy]:5701:
Stats => LocalTopicStatsImpl{creationTime=1542990117898, totalPublishes=0, totalReceivedMessages=0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour might be intentional, since the `LocalTopicStats` are local to the member and `receivedCount` and `publishedCount` are local stats for the client when the operations are performed from the client.

I created a [Github issue](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/14167) on Hazelcast repository regarding this behaviour. Please follow the discussion over there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback